# Func Chain - Method Name Expected

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, func

My intentions is to chain few methods in Func and execute them one by one to get response regarding Function executed successfully or not. Below is my code but unable to Invoke func after getting it from GetInvocationList because it expecting some Method Name. Kindly Advise to fix it...

```
            Func<bool> funcList = null;
            funcList += Init;
            funcList += Process;
            foreach(var func in funcList.GetInvocationList()) {
                bool execuationStatus = func();

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method to :

```
Func<bool> funcList = null;
            funcList += Init;
            funcList += Process;
            foreach (var func in funcList.GetInvocationList())
            {
                var fn = func as Func<bool>;
                bool execuationStatus = fn();
            }
```

GetInvokationList returns Delegate[] and you cannot invoke on it. There is difference between Delegate class vs delegate keyword. As per MSDN documentation :

> The Delegate class is the base class for delegate types. However, only
>   the system and compilers can derive explicitly from the Delegate class
>   or from the MulticastDelegate class. It is also not permissible to
>   derive a new type from a delegate type. The  Delegate class is not
>   considered a delegate type; it is a class used to derive delegate
>   types.
>
> Most languages implement a delegate keyword, and compilers for those
>   languages are able to derive from the  MulticastDelegate class;
>   therefore, users should use the delegate keyword provided by the
>   language.

Comment: If one function return false, how to call this function again??

Comment: @JosephCenk I think I didn't get the your question. Can you explain it bit

Comment: If Process got any exception,how can I repeat this function again

Comment: Though i don't have background about what you trying achieve but it appears to be broad topic around exception handling and re-trying policies. Like for what exception you want to repeat, any ?